# Run application in response to database event

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a an application that needs to run at the end of a series of database jobs in SQL Server 2005. The application will do processing on the data that was created by these jobs.

What would be the best way to trigger the execution of this application?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of application, if it's non-interactive then you can write [CLR stored procedure](http://tinyurl.com/2zz7pk) that can be executed like any other stored procedure call.

Comment: I think your mention of the word 'event' translates to triggers in the sql server database. So try clr triggers too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179562%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having the application run on the database server, just add a new job step and execute it as part of the job.  The command type is "operating system command (CmdExec).